# Mutate rejects function which contains a loop

Tags: r

A function with 2 inputs runs correctly on it's own and when looped over rows, but is found wanting when using mutate.
"### Loop which gives correct answers" is what I'm afer.
"### Where error messages appear" is what doesn't work. THe first row of eff1 is correct, but remaing rows have been rounded using s value from first row.
Why does the mutate not work, please?

```
install.packages("reprex") 
library(reprex)
library(tidyverse)

### Digit extraction
extract_digit <- function(x, n) {
  floor(x / 10^(ceiling(log10(x)) - n )) -  
    floor(x / 10^(ceiling(log10(x)) - n + 1)) * 10
}

### Round 2 numbers "effectively"
effective_digits1 <- function(x, y)
{
  output <- vector("double", 1)  
  n <- floor(log10(x) + 1)
  for(i in 1:n)
  {
    a.i <- extract_digit(x, i)
    b.i <- extract_digit(y, i)
    if (a.i - b.i != 0)
    {
      break
    }
  }
  s = i + 1
  output <- signif(x, s)
  return(output)

}

### Function works correctly 
effective_digits1(6114, 1842)

### Dataframe on which to mutate
motor_vehicles <- data.frame("type_of_vehicle" =
                               c("Private cars and private vans",
                                 "Motorcycles, scooters and mopeds",
                                 "Public transport vehicles",
                                 "Goods",
                                 "Agricultural tractors etc",
                                 "Other vehicles"),
                              "y1961" = c(6114, 1842, 94, 1490, 481,    206),
                              "y1966" = c(9747, 1430, 96, 1611, 478, 260))

### Second df on which to mutate
motor_vehicles2 <- motor_vehicles

### Loop which gives correct answers
for (i in 1:nrow(motor_vehicles)){
  motor_vehicles$eff_1961[i] <-  effective_digits1(motor_vehicles$y1961[i], motor_vehicles$y1966[i])

}

### Where error messages appear
eff1 <- 
  motor_vehicles2 %>% 
  mutate(eff_1961 = effective_digits1(y1961, y1966))

### Loop which gives correct answers - what I'm after
### Where error messages appear - 
Warning messages:
1: In 1:n : numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used
2: In if (a.i - b.i != 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Your loop function is not vectorised? i.e. it works for pairs of singleton numbers it doesn't work for pairs of number vectors as input? And in particular the `if` statement is looking for a single TRUE/FALSE value -- as the error message is hinting.

Comment: In this simple case where you are not using `group_by`, the code `mutate(eff_1961 = effective_digits1(y1961, y1966))` is another way of writing `motor_vehicles2$eff_1961 = effective_digits1(motor_vehicles2$y1961, motor_vehicles2$y1966)`. There's no looping or anything else going on, all it really does is save you needing to type `motor_vehicles2$` before your column names.

Comment: I'd suggest revising the question to be "How can I vectorize the `effective_digits1` function?" A description in words of what the function does, with a few sample inputs and outputs, would be very helpful for that.

Comment: Thanks for the responses and sorry not to have been clearer: first post and still learning how to cut to the chase.